# Android Show Storage PopUp

Tags: android, dialog, popup

I have an android application which will download a file and save it to storage. I want my application shows a popup which show all the list files in the /sdcard and make the user choose where the downloaded file will be placed.

I know how to download the file, but i don't know how to show the popup like that. Anyone can help me?